# Using Math mode in the package acronym

Tags: acronyms

I am using the `\usepackage[printonlyused,nohyperlinks]{acronym}` package. I want to include a math character in the definition. This is how I defined it:

```
\acro{L1AC}[$\mathcal{L}_1$-AC]{$\mathcal{L}_1$ Adaptive Control}
```

And I referred to it as `\ac{L1AC}`. Everything works, except the acronym of curly L shows up as an arrow (see picture below). Any ideas?

Here is a minimal template of what I am using:

```
\documentclass[gpscopy,onehalfspacing,11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[printonlyused,nohyperlinks]{acronym}
\renewcommand{\acsfont}[1]{{\scshape \MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\justifying

\chapter{Glossary}
\begin{acronym}[ANOVA]
\acro{L1AC}[$\mathcal{L}_1$-AC]{$\mathcal{L}_1$ Adaptive Control}
\end{acronym}

\chapter{Some Chapter}
to assess the application of the so-called novel \ac{L1AC} \cite{hovakimyan2010} as applied to closed-loop control in anesthesia using

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @darthbith, of course. I'll do that right now.

Comment: @darthbith, I updated the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the answer to your question, but now that you've posted the MWE, I hope someone will be able to help you quickly! I'll delete my comment :-)

Comment: @darthbith, thanks for the tips :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a question of untimely expansion. Define a robust command for `\mathcal{L}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage[printonlyused,nohyperlinks]{acronym}
\renewcommand{\acsfont}[1]{{\scshape \MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\mL}{\mathcal{L}}


\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}[ANOVA]
\acro{L1AC}[$\mL_1$-AC]{$\mL_1$ Adaptive Control}
\end{acronym}

Here I use the acronym \ac{L1AC}

And again \ac{L1AC}

\end{document}
```

[image]